# Regex help to exclude

Tags: regex

I've been using this query in a variable (in Grafana) for some time:

```
/hq-sw-/gm
```

Which gives me anything starting with 'hq-sw-', however something has been added called 'hq-sw-3850' that is messing up my results and I need to exclude it and I'm having no luck with my regex.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see the help on how to ask a question. Add a tag for Grafana. There exist many regex dialects and ways they're used.

Comment: Use a negative lookahead: `(?!3850)`